# how to write a .rar file received from a XMLHttpRequest responce to a directory

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to send a .rar file from a server to a client and I do it with app.get response(res.download) and on the client-side, I receive it with an XMLHttpRequest. How can I write the response to a directory as a .rar file without using a browser?

Answer (score 0):

[Express JS Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

```js
app.get('/downloads/myfile.rar', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('../public/myfile.rar')
})
```

in your browser you will want to will want to a `target='_blank'` so it opens in a new tab to trigger the download

```html
<a href='http://localhost:8080/downloads/myfile.rar' target='_blank'>download</a>
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to do it without using a browser as a node app.

Comment: are you saying you are trying to download a .rar file to a server?

Comment: I'm trying to download it to a folder on my phone with an app im making. Kinda like how google play does it.